# Adding a Path to a String in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating an output file using `FileSystemObject` in Excel VBA, and I want to enable the user to choose the location where to save his output using a *FileDialog* box.

Here is a s snippet of my code,

```
Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
Dim tsStream As TextStream
Dim strFilePath as String
Dim FD as FileDialog

Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

With FD
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = -1 Then
        For Each i in .SelectedItems
            strFilePath = i
        Next i
    Else

    End If
End With
Set FD = Nothing

Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject
Set tsStream = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strFilePath &".txt", True)
```

The problem is the code's "Save as type:" is Excel file types.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Try here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19856764/1274820

Answer (score 2):

You can't set filters to `msoFileDialogSaveAs`, instead of that, to browse to a filepath, use `msoFileDialogFilePicker`. Now you can set filters.

```
Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
FD.Filters.Clear
FD.Filters.Add "Text file", "*.txt"
```