# Word VBA force save as .docm

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've ended up cleaning up someone's mess on a Word document that's used throughout my company. It is a macro-heavy document that needs to be saved as a `.docm` exclusively. I'm worried about it getting "save as"-d as something other than a `.docm`, but I can't seem to find a way to limit the save as file picker or swap out the extension on save as while still using VBA.

How can I achieve this?

Edit: Some of the things I've tried, to no avail:
This has the right idea, but doesn't actually limit the filetypes down on save https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/how-to-set-path-for-wddialogfilesaveas-dialog/535b7f9c-9972-425c-8483-35387a97d61d

Towards the bottom, Microsoft says that SaveAs isn't compatible with filter.clear and filter.add https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa219834(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: It's a superuser.stackexchange.com question

Comment: probably should show the code for your file picker.....

Comment: Google says http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856592/file-selector-how-do-i-specify-filetype

Comment: @Chrismas007 I was able to get something like that to work, but only for opening a file, not for limiting the save as. As far as I can tell, Word VBA doesn't support the filters.clear and filter.add property in the save as operation

Comment: @user2820382 Sounds like you have done quite a bit of research that you haven't included in your question.

Comment: @Chrismas007 Sorry, this is the first time I've had to actually ask a question! Edits coming shortly

Comment: Are you implementing your own FileDialog? If so, please show how you're doing this. I have an idea but would prefer not to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: @DavidZemens I am not, I've just been trying to more or less hijack the existing save as process.

Comment: Would it suffice to merely prevent the user from doing `SaveAs` operation? Or do they occasionally need to rename the file?

Comment: @DavidZemens Unfortunately they need to be able to rename it and save it elsewhere. Obviously there are other ways to accomplish this outside of the SaveAs operation but non-technical users will get frustrated if they can't do it within Word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to hijack the native "SaveAs" dialog in Word, you need to lever the Application-level event for `DocumentBeforeSave`, and then call the FileDialog manually, in order to validate the extension.

### 1. Create a standard code module and name it `modEventHandler`. Put the following code in it.

```
Option Explicit
Public TrapFlag As Boolean
Public cWordObject As New cEventClass

'You may not need these in a DOCM, but I needed to implement this in an ADD-IN

Sub TrapEvents()
If TrapFlag Then
    Exit Sub
End If
Set cWordObject.DOCEvent = Application
TrapFlag = True

End Sub
Sub ReleaseTrap()
If TrapFlag Then
    Set cWordObject.DOCEvent = Nothing
    Set cWordObject = Nothing
    TrapFlag = False
End If
End Sub
```

### 2. Create a Class Module called `cEventClass` and put this code in the module:

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents DOCEvent As Application

Private Sub DOCEvent_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
' Do not prevent SAVEAS for *other* documents
If ObjPtr(Doc) <> ObjPtr(ThisDocument) Then
    Exit Sub
End If

If SaveAsUI Then
    ' The user has invoked SAVE AS command , so we will hijack this and use our own FileDialog
    Call CustomSaveAs(Doc)
    ' Prevent duplicate appearance of the SAVEAS FileDialog
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub

Private Sub CustomSaveAs(ByRef Doc As Document)
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim filename$

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
fd.Show
If fd.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
filename = fd.SelectedItems(1)
If Not Right(filename, 4) = "docm" Then
    ' ### DO NOT EXECUTE this dialog unless it matches our .DOCM file extension
    MsgBox "This document should only be saved as a DOCM / Macro-Enabled Document", vbCritical, "NOT SAVED!"
Else
    fd.Execute
End If
End Sub
```

### 3. In `ThisDocument` module, do the following code:

```
Private Sub Document_Close()
Call modEventHandler.ReleaseTrap
End Sub

Private Sub Document_Open()
Call modEventHandler.TrapEvents
End Sub
```

### How Does This Work?

`ThisDocument` raises the `Document_Open` event which calls on the `TrapEvents` procedure.

`TrapEvents` procedure creates a `WithEvents` instance of `Word.Application` class, exposing additional events to automation. One of these is `DocumentBeforeSave`.

We use the `DocumentBeforeSave` event to trap the `SaveAs` operation. If the User has requested a `SaveAs`, then we force the dialog with logic as created in `CustomSaveAs` procedure. This uses simple logic to test the file extension provided, and prevents the document from being saved if it is not a DOCM extension.  If the FileDialog does receive a valid DOCM extension, then we `Execute` the dialog which saves the file as the new name.

Comment: Brilliant—I ran this in a test document and it behaves exactly as it needs to. Thank you so much!

Comment: Cheers. I do zero professional development in Word VBA but it is very similar to Excel and PowerPoint, and many similar principles like this can be applied. There may be ways to improve this of course, but it should be a good place to start! Good luck!