# Open the Save As dialog and default to filtype ".xlsb"

Tags: excel, vba

I want a macro that, when run, will open the Save As dialog with the default filetype an Excel Binary file.

[image]

I tried:

```
Sub Macro()
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
End Sub
```

This opens the dialog, but can't seem to find where I can set the default type.

Comment: Hi Warcupine, unfortunately not it only allows you to filter files by type for selection -- but not save as a default type

Comment: Ohh, whoops mornings coffee etc...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File selector, How do i specify filetype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856592/file-selector-how-do-i-specify-filetype)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub saveAsXlsbDialog()
   Dim fileSaveName As String, FileName As String, filt As String
   
   FileName = "MyXLSB wb"
   filt = "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsb)," & "*.xlsb"
   fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=FileName, _
                   fileFilter:=filt, Title:="Save AS  MACRO ENABLED (xlsb):")
    Debug.Print fileSaveName
    
    'the above code only helps you easily setting the desired full name.
    'to really save it:
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'use here what you need
    If fileSaveName <> "False" Then
         wb.saveas fileSaveName, 50
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the code. I seem to be getting two errors: one on the Debug.Print line, and another on the "If fileSaveName <> False" line. I can't seem to diagnose why though, any thoughts? Does it run ok when you try it?

Comment: I am driving... What error? The code should only stop on that line to let you ser the full name. Does return such a name in Immediate Window? If yes, it continues only after you press F5, as stated...

Comment: @FaneDuru i think it is the type mismatch error where `fileSaveName As String` then comparing `If fileSaveName <> False`

Comment: @k1dr0ck Yes, you are right. Initially, I only posted the part returning `fileSaveName`. Then, I was not attempted to variable declaration. I will adapt the code. Thanks! Adapted... But I was confused about the affirmation regarding the `Debug.Print` line, which I could not imagine what problem can be...

Comment: @TheFriendlyAsker Please, check the adapted code. I also eliminated the `Stop` after `Debug.print` and the code runs without stopping...

Comment: @FaneDuru ,I tried on my PC and I can confirm that it works as it should.